# Lagom: events are not json seralized in cassandra

Tags: json, serialization, cassandra, lagom

I need my events to be stored as json in cassandra (So I can read them with some gui client directly from db).

I've followed lagom's guide https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/Serialization.html (Enabling JSON Serialization), but events are still stored in something like binary or other format.

Here is what I've done:

**Created Serializer Registry**

```
object ProjectSerializerRegistry extends JsonSerializerRegistry {
  override def serializers: Seq[JsonSerializer[_]] = Seq(
    JsonSerializer[ProjectCreated],    
  )
}
```

**Registered it:**

```
abstract class ProjectsApplication(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    with CassandraPersistenceComponents
    with LagomKafkaComponents
    with AhcWSComponents {

  ...
  // Register the JSON serializer registry
  override lazy val jsonSerializerRegistry = ProjectSerializerRegistry
}
```

**Here is the event itself:**

```
case class ProjectCreated(id: String, name: String, createdAt: DateTime) extends ProjectEvent

object ProjectCreated {
  implicit val format: OFormat[ProjectCreated] = Json.format[ProjectCreated]
}
```

After sending command to entity which causes `ProjectCreated` event and executing query `select event from projects.messages` I expected to see something like this in cassandra:

```
{
   "id": "prj-1",
   "name": "Project 1",
   "createdAt": "2018-05-04 01:16:00" 
}
```

But instead, I see something like this in `event` column:

`0x7b226d657373616765223a224869227d`

Did I miss something? Or may be it is some compressed or encoded json value?

Comment: Where do you see that `event` value? Are you using `cqlsh` or some other tool to query Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

This is in hexadecimal format. You can convert it into string using online hex-to-string decoder like https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter or can create one on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The events are stored in binary blobs. if you want to decode these values, you can use the cassandra function `blobAsText`:

```sql
select blobastext(event) from table.messages
```

This shows the decoded event. If it results in a json object, your serialization works correctly.

There is also a `textAsBlob` function.